# How do I display the title of a custom indicator on trading view chart

Tags: pine-script

I have a custom 9 ema indicator built with pinescript and I would like to display their respective number of the ema right of each ema line. I'm not sure how to do it.
Here is my code so far, 2 out of 9 emas. I've also attched a picture[image]

```
//indicator(title='3ema', shorttitle='9EMA', overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)


//Format for a 3
len1 = input.int(3, minval=1, title='Length')
src1 = input(close, title='Source')
out1 = ta.ema(src1, len1)
plot(out1,  color=color.new(color.green, 0), title='3' )
//End of format

//Format for a 8
len2 = input.int(8, minval=1, title='Length')
src2 = input(close, title='Source')
out2 = ta.ema(src2, len2)
plot(out2, color=color.new(color.yellow, 0), title='8')
show_title8 = input.bool(title='8',defval=true)
//End of format
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly do that.

One thing you can do is enable indicators name and value labels.

[image]

## Edit (with labels):

Now that we have labels, you can do that with labels. It will be on your chart though - not on the price scale.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='3ema', shorttitle='9EMA', overlay=true)

//Format for a 3
len1 = input.int(3, minval=1, title='Length')
src1 = input(close, title='Source')
out1 = ta.ema(src1, len1)
plot(out1,  color=color.new(color.green, 0), title='3' )

lbl1 = label.new(bar_index, out1, "EMA" + str.tostring(len1) + ": " + str.tostring(out1, format.mintick), color=color.new(color.white, 100), textcolor=color.green, style=label.style_label_left)
label.delete(lbl1[1])
//End of format

//Format for a 8
len2 = input.int(8, minval=1, title='Length')
src2 = input(close, title='Source')
out2 = ta.ema(src2, len2)
plot(out2, color=color.new(color.yellow, 0), title='8')
show_title8 = input.bool(title='8',defval=true)

lbl2 = label.new(bar_index, out2, "EMA" + str.tostring(len2) + ": " + str.tostring(out2, format.mintick), color=color.new(color.white, 100), textcolor=color.yellow, style=label.style_label_left)
label.delete(lbl2[1])
//End of format
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
you create labels and position them the same place as the ema lines. the color is the color of the label, i have set the alpha of the color.rgb to 100 to make the label invisible.

```
if barstate.islast 
    label.new(bar_index+1, out1, text="out1", color=color.rgb(0,0,0,100),textcolor=(255,255,255,50),textalign=text.align_left,style=label.style_label_left,size=size.small)
```